# What is the fastest way to return large amount of data from Rust FFI library back to C# caller?

Tags: c#, serialization, rust, dllimport, ffi

I am developing a program in .NET C# that calls my own Rust library through Rust FFI, using extern C keyword and loaded by DllImport.

I am doing this because I want to delegate the complicated computation to Rust. After processing from Rust library, it is expected to return a very large amount of data back to C#. Those data should be in a kind of `List<MyDataRecord>` when it is consumed in C#.

Then my questions are:

1. From Rust, what is the best way to pass back those data? Through a pointer to a block of memory arranged like an array of structs?
2. How can C# get back such memory block pointer? Any thread safety concerns here?
3. How to quickly convert such memory block of data to my `List<MyDataRecord>` in C#?

Comment: This was [cross posted to Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/3zhpj0/what_is_the_fastest_way_to_return_large_amount_of/)

Answer (score 1):

The first question we need to answer is: Who will be responsible for allocating and freeing the memory? If you know in advance how many elements will be returned, then you can have either the C# code or the Rust code allocate memory. If you don't know in advance how many elements will be returned, then you have 2 options: 1) have the C# code ask the Rust code how many elements will be returned (if that's possible), then allocate memory from C#; 2) have the Rust code allocate memory. If you allocate managed memory from C# (e.g. a managed array), then you can let the garbage collector free the memory. If you allocate unmanaged memory from C# or from Rust, you'll have to use the correct function to free the memory. If you use Rust's default memory allocator, the Rust code will need to provide a function to free the memory. Remember that the Rust code that produces the results will need to explicitly "leak" the array/`Vec`, otherwise your function will free the memory before returning!

You'll find it difficult to use .NET's `List<T>` type with unmanaged code. You should instead use arrays.

Another important aspect to consider is the struct's layout. You'll have to add `#[repr(C)]` to the Rust struct and either `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]` or `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]` (depending on the types inside your struct) to the C# struct to ensure that both sides lay out the struct's fields in the same way in memory.

When you define the `DllImport` for your Rust function in your C# code, you can annotate the parameters and the return value with the [`MarshalAs` attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to tell the .NET runtime how the arguments and the return value should be marshaled or unmarshaled. In particular, the [`UnmanagedType` enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.unmanagedtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has the `LPArray` member that could be helpful in your situation, though note that [it uses `CoTaskMemAlloc` and `CoTaskMemFree` to manage memory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6cfh6e6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). If the Rust code is responsible for allocating memory, you could also perform the unmarshaling manually by defining the pointer as `IntPtr` and using [`Marshal.PtrToStructure`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn261463%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to unmarshal the structure and [`Marshal.SizeOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn261466%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to offset the pointer to the next element.